# xlwings calls a python function that should create a file, but no file get created

Tags: python, excel, xlwings

```
def create_file():
    file_writer= open('testFile.txt','w')
    file_writer.write('TESTING...;\n')
    file_writer.flush()
    file_writer.close()

def my_macro():
    wb = Workbook.caller()  # Creates a reference to the calling Excel file
    Range('Sheet1', 'C3').value = random.randint(0,10)
    updateValue = Range('Sheet1', 'C3').value
    print("updatedValue=" , updateValue);
    create_file()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'FirstExcel.xlsm'))
    Workbook.set_mock_caller(path)
    my_macro()
```

When I run the above code in Eclipse, it creates a file and updates the excel spreadsheet. However, when I run it from excel it updates the spreadsheet, but does not create a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that Excel currently starts the Python interpreter in a different working directory than when you call the file from Python. It's an open issue on GitHub, see [here](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/23).

In the meantime, just use an absolute/full path for all your files in `open` and `write`. You should also be able to use something like `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'testFile.txt'))`