# xlwings to write a text file locally

Tags: python, xlwings

Hi I am looking to export data from the excel workbook out to my desktop as a text or an XML file.
I have it formed into an XML file and I am writing it locally when in DEBUG mode *but* when I add in the UDF and try run the same code it wont save the file.

Anyone any ideas as to why this wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to specify the Absolute Path for the creation of the file.
further information can be found here
[xlwings calls a python function that should create a file, but no file get created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31840145/xlwings-calls-a-python-function-that-should-create-a-file-but-no-file-get-creat)